# writing and using custom JS functions in lab.js

Tags: javascript, function

I have a question on writing & using custom functions in **lab.js** studies:

I defined a function in a component at the beginning of the script and I’d like to use it in the following components in my study, but for some reason it doesn’t work.

I can call the function in the component where I defined it, but if I try to call it a few components later, it throws a ReferenceError and says the function is not defined.
Any clues what might be the issue here?

I think I’m not defining my function correctly at the beginning of the experiment but I’m not entirely sure. This is my code for the function:

```
const extend = function(array1, array2){
    var array1, array2;
    return Array.from(array1).concat(Array.from(array2));
}
```

This is how I call the function:

```
extend([1,2], [3,4,5]);
```

And this is where you can find the .json for the experiment:
https://github.com/MMarieSchuckart/stackoverflow_demo

Thanks in advance for any ideas/hints!

-Merle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I tried about 100 things and apparently, it's not enough to declare the function using `const` or `var`, you need to use `window.` to make it global.

The solution looks like this:

```
window.extend = function(array1, array2){
    var array1, array2;
    return Array.from(array1).concat(Array.from(array2));
}
```